# CakePHP: HABTM not performing join properly on habtmDelete call

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

We are upgrading from Cake 1.2 to 1.3.8, and using the ExtendedAssociations behavior.

One of the problems we are having, is in our **Store** model, which has a HABTM relationship to **Module** via **stores_modules**.

Retrieving the data is all good, but one issue moving to 1.3.8 seems to have introduced is that when we want to delete all **Modules** from the **Store** - in the Stores model

> $this->habtmDeleteAll('Module', $this->id);

The problem is that this produces the following SQL query (as it is SELECTING all stores_modules first, to see what to delete)

> SELECT `StoresModule`.`module_id` FROM `stores_modules` AS `StoresModule`   WHERE `StoresModule`.`store_id` = 1 AND `Module`.`system_default` = 0

_

> 2011-03-29 18:27:46 Warning: Warning (512): SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Module.system_default' in 'where clause' in [/usr/lib/cakephp_1.3.8/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php, line 684]

So it appears the problem is that the above SQL statement is not adding the JOIN to the **modules** table.. hence it cannot fine `Module`.`system_default`

Any help on this would be great, it's really got me stumped :)

Chris.

Comment: 1.2->1.3.8, maybe there are a few changelogs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand, but it appears you are not calling your models correctly. If you need to delete all associated model records, you would probably do something like this:

```
$this->Store->Modules->deleteAll(array('Store.id' => $id), true, false);
```

NOT TESTED!